# 3 day old sourdough starter splits after feeding

Tags: bread, flour, yeast, sourdough, starter

My starter consists out of 150gr All purpose, 60 grams of whole wheat and 210 grams of water.

On day 2 it bubbled nicely, but I fed it only with half a feeding fearing it would otherwise not stay within the jar. It then rose within hours to double size and then starter to split (hooch). I then fed it again (10 hours after 1st feeding on day 2) with a full feeding (1:1:1 ratio). So in total it received 1,5 feeding on day 2, half in the morning and regular feeding in the evening.

The next morning it did bubble on top, doesn't rise and stays splitting (although very slowly). Now, halfway through day 3 without additional feeding nothing changed.

Should I feed it again? I don't think it already processed the last feeding on day 2.

Temperature is constantly between 20-25degrees Celsius.

Help please..

Answer (score 3):

Stir.  Remove half.  Feed.  Continue the process.  You should always remove some at each feeding, to keep the acidity in check. I sometimes remove up to a half for each feeding.  It should take at least a week to become usable.

Comment: That's certainly true when building it up, but with an established starter kept in the fridge, you can get away with discarding at every other feed if you use a decent proportion of the starter each time.  I don't discard my discard, instead using it for pizza, and my pizza-making habits fit better to taking some at every other feed.  Also I feed in the morning to use in the evening, and use 4/5 as much as I added.

Comment: @ChrisH  for sure.  In fridge, i sometimes go a couple of weeks with no problem.  OP is on day 2.  ...and using the "discard" is smart.

Comment: Plus: pizza.  But none for me for a few days as I'm rebuilding my starter from what survived in the bottom of the jar after knocking it on the floor yesterday

Comment: @ChrisH yikes! Good thing that a spoonful of starter is enough to get everything back on track.

Comment: @moscafj I followed up on your advice. I'll send an update tomorrow.

Comment: @ChrisH 'with an established starter kept in the fridge, you can get away with' only doing replenishment feeds after you use it if you use it at least once a week or so. That's been my policy for the last 10 years or so, I only do a discard if I'm going away for a fortnight.

Comment: @Spagirl similar here except I replenish about 12 hours before using, leaving it out of the fridge to wake it up.  I tend to make bread about twice a week and pizza once a fortnight (making enough for 2 and freezing half the dough)

Comment: @moscafj It thriving atm. Thanks! After feeding it doubles within hours, then I stir it down and it doubles again within 3/4 hours.